# cannot trace the value of a slider in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I tried this

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;
import fl.controls.Slider;
```

...

```
  public function init( e:Event ):void {

    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
    addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,_handleSlider);

  }         

  public function _handleSlider(event:SliderEvent) {
      trace(event.target.value);
  }
```

Flash doesn't like 
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderEvent.

Comment: What is init a part of? I'm expecting the `addEventListener` to be a method of the `BaseButton` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about the Slider component then you need to listen for the `SliderEvent.CHANGE`
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa1.html

Comment: I tried but I get Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event. 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderEvent.

Comment: Did you import the event? import fl.events.SliderEvent;

Comment: you need to import fl.events.SliderEvent;

Comment: ah ok I see flash.events is not same as fl.events

Answer (score 1):

```
trace(Slider(event.target).value);
```

Comment: thanks but it says cannot convert from fl.controls::BaseButton@273d41c9 to  fl.controls.Slider.

Answer (score 1):

Those error messages mean those types weren't imported correctly. So looking at your import statements I see the probable mistake. You wrote flash.events.* but this documentation indicates that SliderEvent is in the package fl.events

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/events/SliderEvent.html

That's pretty stupid though since there's also the package flash.events but oh well there you go. You need to import both flash.events.* *and* fl.events.SliderEvent

Comment: yeah thanks I'm very beginner so I didn't see it in first place :)